# How to submit a script transaction using `cardano-cli`

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, alonzo

I'm trying to go through the Alonzo Testnet exercises to get more familiar with the deployment process for Plutus contracts. I've gotten confused by the instructions in [sheet 3](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/f062d9ff3e11c4216eb8b3340d74c5b1330f14ae/Alonzo-exercises/alonzo-purple/3_Alonzo-purple-exercise-3.md):

> Download the pre-built AlwaysSucceeds.plutus Plutus script, and obtain the script address. `cardano-cli address build …`

I've downloaded the file and saved it as `AlwaysSucceeds.plutus` but when I run the command:

```
cardano-cli address build --payment-script-file AlwaysSucceeds.plutus --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

I get the error:

```
Command failed: address build  Error: AlwaysSucceeds.plutus: AlwaysSucceeds.plutus: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The ellipses `...` are throwing me off, like it's supposed to be obvious what to include. Could someone point me in the right direction of what I'm missing? Maybe I just skipped some docs, but I suspect I'll be similarly confused with subsequent ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

Your command invocation looks correct. But the error suggests that the file `AlwaysSucceeds.plutus` is not in the directory where you are running the command. Either make sure you run the command from the directory the file is in, or give the full path to the file.

Comment: I've given the full path, and that doesn't help. I'm running from the Docker container, so I thought maybe the CLI's path was from in the container. I've tried copying the Plutus file over to the container and using the absolute path, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `AlwaysSucceeds.plutus: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)` means the file is missing.